# Changing backslashes to forward slashes changes file size

Tags: batch-file, filesize

I have two small to medium sized files (2k) that are for all intents and purposes identical.  The second file is the result of the first file being duplicated and replacing backslashes with forward slashes.  The new file is bigger by 80 bytes (or one byte per line).

I did this with a simple batch script,and at first I thought the script might have unintentionally added some spaces or other artifacts.  Or maybe the fact that their extensions are different has something to do with it (one has a `tmp` extension and the other has a `lst` extension).

From an editor, I replaced all  forward slashes in the new file with backslashes and saved it without changing the extension.

*And, hey guess what?*  The files were the same size again.

Now, before this is written off as a random fluke, I also see the same behavior exhibited in three other pairs of files (in other words six files) created in the same manner as the first.  They are all one byte bigger per line in the file.  The largest is about 12k bytes, and the smallest is about 2k.

I wouldn't think it has anything to do with escaping because I am on a Windows box using the Windows 7 `cmd.exe` shell.

Also one other thing.  I tried the following:

```
  echo \\\\\ >> a.txt
  echo ///// >> b.txt
```

The files matched in size (7 bytes)

Does anyone have an explanation for this behavior?

Comment: Can you post the script that you used? It would help people replicate it...

Comment: First thing I'd do is check them out in a hex editor. My guess is that the line endings are being changed in the process of saving.

Comment: What software/program do you used to convert slashes? I would bet in UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: See my answer.  Turns out to be less exciting than I hoped.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest opening the files with an editor like [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) that shows the type of linefeed (Windows/Mac/Unix). This is most likely your problem if the file size differs 1 byte per line.

Notepad++ can show line endings as small CR/LF symbols (View -> Show Symbol -> Show End of Line) and convert between the Windows/Mac/Unix line endings (Edit -> EOL Conversion).

Both Unix and Mac systems are usually storing files with an one byte line ending (Mac: CR, Unix: LF), Windows uses two bytes (CR LF).

Depending on the programs your batch scripts use, this might occur even though your system is a pure Windows box. The reason you don't get a difference when using an editor is that editors usually keep the file's original line endings.

Answer (score 0):

Okay.  I just solved it.  @schnaader pointed me in the right direction.  It actually has nothing to do with the forward or backslashes.

What happened is that my script added one character of trailing white space to each line.  Why the file again became the same size after I reverted the slashes is because the editor I used to find and replace (Komodo Edit) is set up to automatically trim trailing white space on file save.

Funny.

Comment: OK, slightly different, but similar. Btw, this can be easily detected with Notepad++, too (View -> Show Symbol -> Show White Space and TAB) :)

Comment: I used Notepad++ after your suggestion.  It was a definitely the right place to look.  Thanks